# How to set up a social media feed with vue and axios

Tags: ajax, javascript, feed

What I need is a social media stream with posts with the Hashtag mnbasel form Instagram, Facebook and Twitter. I couldn’t find any good tutorial. Hopefully someone can tell me what I miss or lead me to a tutorial.

I signed in to Instagram as a developer and got my Access Token using Client ID and Client Secret.

Then I created a Vue component with this script:

```
 module.exports = {
  name: 'socialstream',
  data: function () {
    return {
      instagram: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getEntries();
  },
  methods: {
    getEntries () {
      axios.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=mnbasel&access_token={access-token}')
        .then(response => {
          this.instagram = response.data.data
        })
    }
  }
}
```

What I get from this is the following error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

And this is the Result I get when I paste the URL in the Browser:

```
"code": 400,
"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException",
"error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."
```

I also installed the OAuth Plugin from Dukt and configured Instagram. Not sure if I need that and how to connect this information with the Vue component.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one of two things:

Its possible that you are not actually injecting your accesstokem with the following string

```
'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=mnbasel&access_token={access-token}'
```

I believe it should be :

```
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=mnbasel&access_token=${access-token}`
```

If you still get the oauth error, you may need to ensure that your access token has the correct scope in instagrams dev

Comment: Dear Brett, sorry for not responding to your answer. I solved it with a plugin and forgot about my question. Thanks a lot anyway! Cheers

Comment: Dear user2190590, could you please outline the solution that has worked for you? (You can do so either in form of an answer, or an update to the question itself.) This would help others who come across a similar challenge. Cheers!